# Pandas dataframe Sum for specific years

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I just started using Pandas for my analytics work.

I have a dataframe in Pandas with over 2 million rows, suppose it's called DF.
I need to create a variable that shows me the SUM of a column called "Total Records" but separate it by year, so lets say, one variable for 2017, another for 2018 and another one for 2019.
Problem is, my DATE column is formatted like so: 1/20/2018
Is there anything like the SQL syntax:

```
Select Sum("Total Records") 
From DF
Where date like '%2018';
```

?

i have attempted to use df.query('date == 2018')['Total Records'].sum(), but it gives me a syntax error.

Suppose the DF looks like so:

```
Date      | Total Records
1-20-2019 | 100
3-12-2018 | 50
5-14-2019 | 100
3-10-2018 | 20
```

I want it to output the variables like this

```
TotalRecords2018 = 70;
TotalRecords2019 = 200;
```

Comment: First, make your column `datetime` dtype. `df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])`. Then, `groupby` the year and sum: `df.groupby(df['Date'].dt.year).sum()`

Comment: @rafaelc thank you! I forgot to mention though, that the DF has 55 columns, I only wish to sum Total Records. I tried sum('Total Records') but it threw an error.

Comment: Then use `df.groupby(....)['Total Records'].sum()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Approach 1**: The recommended approach is to convert the type of 'Date' column into datetime.

Something like

`df['Date'] = df['Date'].astype('datetime64')`

Then separate the year and apply aggregate 'sum'

OR

**Approach 2**: Splitting the string

If you want to retain the data type, split the string based on '-'.

`df['day', 'month', 'year'] = df.Date.split("-",expand=True)`

Use the new column 'year' to groupby and sum.

`df.groupby('year")['Total Records'].sum()`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
e = df

e.Date = (e.Date.apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, format="%d-%M-%Y"))).dt.strftime('TotalRecords%Y')  
e.groupby('Date')['Total Records'].sum().to_dict() 

# {'TotalRecords2018': 70, 'TotalRecords2019': 200}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one example using groupby method in pandas.

```
import pandas as pd

data = [["1-20-2019", 100], ["3-12-2018", 50], ["5-14-2019", 100], ["3-10-2018", 20]]
columns = ["Date", "Total Records"]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']) 

result = df.groupby(df.Date.dt.to_period("Y"))['Total Records'].sum()

for year, records in result.items():
    print(f"TotalRecords{year} = {records}")
```

output

```
TotalRecords2018 = 70
TotalRecords2019 = 200
```

Comment: Thank you. I've managed to do it with the solutions provided so far.

Another silly question: If I import pandas as pd, would I still be able to use both pandas and pd for calls?

Comment: what is "import pandas as pd" doing is importing pandas and renames it to pd. So instead of typing all the time pandas you type pd. To answer your question if you renamed pandas to pd, you can't use pandas library, you have to use pd - an allies for pandas.